# What makes an electron flip to spin-up?

Tags: spin-models

The normal mode of spin for an electron is *spin down*:
[image]

with angular momentum L pointing in the opposite direction of motion V (right)

but, when a free electron approaches , say, a Helium ion it must , according to Pauli's, flip its spin in the the direction of motion (left: *spin up*)

What makes the electron  flip over? who provides the energy for the change? Does the energy required vary form case to case, and if so, what is the formula?

Comment: I think you're describing the [helicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicity_(particle_physics)), in which case the helicity can be left or right handed. Are you mixing up helicity and chirality? (If so you wouldn't be the first :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie, probably I am confused, can you write one of your legendary clear answers and clarify what happens when a spin-down electron is taken by  He+. is the picture correct?

Comment: [Have a read through this blog post](https://www.quantumdiaries.org/2011/06/19/helicity-chirality-mass-and-the-higgs/) for more on helicity and chirality. This is the clearest explanation I've read.

Comment: @JohnRennie, Thanks, I will, but the question is a bit different: whatever changes (helicity/chirality), *what* makes a free electron adapt it to Pauli's?

Comment: Remember that you can have a helium atom with two spin aligned electrons if they are in different shells. Then the excited state can decay to the ground state by emitting a photon.

Comment: @JohnRennie, yes, but I am referring to the the basic form when an electron is acquired in the ground state and, as they say not specifying helicity/chirality,   must have different spin. (up, *right*?). Who provides the energy to make it flip over and change its spin (Helicity/chirality)?

Comment: I don't think you're describing a physically relevant situation. An electron coming in from infinity towards a He$^+$ ion cannot just settle into the ground state because it has too much energy and that energy has to be shed somehow.

Comment: @JohnRennie Do you now something about the history of the spin definition before Goudsmit and Uhlenbeck? About the relation of deflection and rotating electron? The only I know is the rejection of such a rotation of the electron but the term spin considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spin of an electron is an intrinsic and unambiguous property. The spin is related to the electrons magnetic dipole moment and to the direction of the deflection in a magnetic field (Lorentz force). If - by convention - the electrons magnetic dipole moment and the spin are showing in the same direction, then for a positron these two parameters are anti-aligned (and in a magnetic field the moving positron gets deflected in the opposite direction).

In an atom two electrons can occupy the same three quantum numbers if and only if their magnetic dipole moments are anti-aligned. [Pauli realized](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle)...

> ... that the complicated numbers of electrons in closed shells can be reduced to the simple rule of one electron per state, if the electron states are defined using four quantum numbers. For this purpose he introduced a new two-valued quantum number, identified by Samuel Goudsmit and George Uhlenbeck as electron spin.

That is the origin of why there are two understandings of what spin is. But the flip or alignment of the magnetic dipole moments of two electrons in opposite directions has nothing to do with the spin of an electron and the opposite spin in positrons (emanated in Lorentz force and in the direction of induced magnetic fields).

In the comments you ask

> ... the question is a bit different: whatever changes (helicity/chirality), what makes a free electron adapt it to Pauli's (principle).

Simply the electrons orienting each other in such a way that north and south poles near the opposite poles of the other electron. This is the lowest possible energetic and most stable level.

---

user157860 in a comment talks about the 21cm hydrogen line. The most detailed information I found on this [Wikipedia page](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) (Google translation):

> The forbidden line of neutral hydrogen is caused by the interaction of the magnetic moments of an electron and a proton in a hydrogen atom. The energy of the hydrogen atom with parallel arrangement of the magnetic moments of the electron and the proton is somewhat larger than in the case of an antiparallel one, so - when a spontaneous change in the orientation of the magnetic moment of the electron in the opposite orientation  - atom emits a quantum of electromagnetic radiation with a wavelength of 21.1 cm (frequency 1420.40575 MHz).
>
> In parallel with the emission of the EM radiation, the reverse process also occurs - the excitation of hydrogen atoms by electromagnetic quanta with high energies or in collision between atoms. Therefore, in interstellar atomic hydrogen, a dynamic equilibrium is established between the radiation events of radio quanta and the excitation of atoms by EM quanta and collisions.

Comment: Since you about hydrogen talking, refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_linem The ground state of neutral hydrogen consists of an electron bound to a proton. Both the electron and the proton have intrinsic magnetic dipole moments ascribed to their spin, whose interaction results in a slight increase in energy when the spins are parallel, and a decrease when antiparallel.

Comment: Thanks, what about Helium? what is the alignment and the difference of energy between spin-up and spin-down? is the electron in He+ spin-down or can it also be spin-up?

Comment: I prefer to talk about the orientation of the MDMs. Of course in He+ the single electron can be excited by collision or EM radiation and it’s MDM can be in the forbidden orientation to some poles of the nucleus (from the 2 protons and 2 neutrons). Emitting a photon it’s fall back to the “right” orientation. Not to forget, that there always is the electrostatic appeal between the negative and positive charges, so the electron in the “wrong” position does not fly away.